# Selenium not return the results when page loaded

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am trying to post some information into webpage and then return some other information after posting and clicking on Login button and this is my code

```
Sub Test()
Dim driver      As New WebDriver
Dim x           As Variant
Dim ele         As SelectElement
Dim s           As String

With driver
    .Start "Chrome", "https://studea.emis.gov.eg"
    .Wait (5000)

sBack:
    .Get "/std_data_mail.aspx"
    .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox3").SendKeys "30904201602611"

    Set ele = .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Dropyear").AsSelect
    ele.SelectByValue 2009

    Set ele = .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Dropmonth").AsSelect
    ele.SelectByIndex 4

    Set ele = .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_DropDay").AsSelect
    ele.SelectByValue 20

    Set ele = .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_DropDownList5").AsSelect
    ele.SelectByIndex 12

    Set ele = .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_DropDownListsex").AsSelect
    ele.SelectByIndex 1

    .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Button2").Click
    .Wait (5000)

    '.FindElementById("").SendKeys ""



    On Error Resume Next
    s = Empty
    s = .FindElementByXPath("/html/body/span/h1").Text
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Left(s, 12) = "Server Error" Then
        If MsgBox("Server Error. Would You Like To Try Again?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then GoTo sBack Else Exit Sub
    Else

        'THIS PART DOESNOT RETURN ANYTHING

        Debug.Print .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtsdname").Text
        Debug.Print .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtsdid").Text
        Debug.Print .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtsdschool").Text
    End If
    Stop
End With

Stop
End Sub
```

The code runs and when there's a server error, a message box appear to tell the user to try again. And when there is a response, I got no data although the page loaded on the driver.
I have commented the lines I got a problem at.

Comment: .get "/std_data_mail.aspx" looks odd. Why is that there? And doesn't it throw an error?

Comment: Try `/index.aspx` . I was just trying something